# Testing PayPal buttons

Tags: vb.net, paypal

I generated a vb.net website to sell some quantity of a book. it's a vb.net site using a SQL server backend. I modeled the book's order form on the paper form the company was using. The form allows customers to specify: name, organization, address, city/state/zip, and quantity.

Once the form is complete, they submit the form to another page which records the form values in a database. I then have them press the add to cart button which is supposed to upload the cart information to paypal for checkout. For some reason the cart opens empty without any errors.

Here is my add to cart info:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="XXXXXX@XXX.XXX" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="2015" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="2015 Catholic Directory" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="15.00" />

<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="<%= Request.Form("add")%>" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />

<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://10.5.0.43/catholicDirectory complete_order.aspx" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2" />

<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" style="width:120px; height:26px;" target="_self"/></center>
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

What I need to know is how do I:

1. Why is my cart opening empty?
2. Get PayPal to redirect back to my website so I can mark the transaction as paid by storing maybe a PayPal transaction ID in my database I researched this and was able to direct them back if they click a link to return, but I don't want them to have to click anything. Research directed me to seller settings in my account but can't find them to set auto return url.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use PayPal's IPN listener. There is an IPN simulator which you can use to make sure it's hitting your site correctly.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/

You'll need to setup 2 accounts within sandbox. A personal and a business. The business account is where you send transations. You can use the personal account to login and test payments.

As for redirecting back after payment, you can set this in both your return URL and inside PayPal

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://yoursite.com/payment-success">
```

You can set auto return by following the directions here: http://wemakewebsites.com/blog/how-to-get-paypal-to-auto-return-to-your-website-after-a-customer-payment

**EDIT:**

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
    <input id="element_1" name="amount" type="text" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="yourbusiness@email.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Payment">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://yourwebsite.com/payment-success">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
    <input type="image" src="http://yourwebsite.com/images/btn-donate.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://yourwebsite.com/includes/paypal_ipn.aspx" />
</form>
```

Once payment is made the user will head over to PayPal to complete the payment. As long as you have the notify_url set with a working listener PayPal will hit it. In that file is where you want to put a few more db collections. PayPal can send you back a bunch of information (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) depending on what data you are looking for. In the following example (https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.vb) You'd want to add your db collection after line 35 where the user has completed payment:

```
If strResponse = "VERIFIED" Then
```

Comment: I checked out the IPN listener and it's written in PHP script which my website's server can not process. my site is .net. I could not see a use for it anyway.

I then checked into the sandbox more and found out that if i submit my add to cart form to the sandbox site I can test the add to cart button on the test site and even make a test payment. I can even see the return action you described.

I did that and created a test account. I tried to checkout but none of my credit cards were accepted. I got site errors trying to contact paypal. what more can I do?

Comment: Yes, their example is in PHP. You would need to write your own. There are tons of uses for it if you are taking payments on PayPal. 1 great reason is recording data from the transaction...

Comment: OK. so I have no idea how to code a listener in .net and don't have the time to learn new code. I'm not even sure how to use the thing if I do create one. All I need to know is that payment has been made and that seems like the redirect after payment would work as I could return to the site and update the database to say that payment was completed.

Comment: They have other code samples you can check out on Git. `https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.vb` as well as search around the net. There's plenty of examples out there.

Comment: I have no idea what I'm doing with the code samples. I know it might seem simple to someone who truly understands .net, but me, I know just enough to work with databases. I can't make heads nor tails with this. I don't even know where to put the code.

Comment: I finally figured out that I need to use the upload function to take the contents of my site's cart and upload to to the paypal cart.

Comment: I edited my question since it's changed now that I've stopped trying to understand the listener.

Comment: For #2, did you follow my link? ` http://wemakewebsites.com/blog/how-to-get-paypal-to-auto-return-to-your-website-after-a-customer-payment` That's the correct location of the Auto-direct URL. Just make sure you are on the Classic site

Comment: Ah, I was not on the classic site and could not find the settings page.

Comment: I actually found it without using the classic site. I just needed to examine the photos from your link a bit better. why does PayPal seem to make everything so difficult?

Comment: oh good! It's not all that bad. once you get and see how things work it's actually really awesome. super convenient too

Comment: Auto return isn't working. I checked the paypal sandbox site and it's turned on and the url is specified, but I'm getting the link to return without being automatically returned. Might you know why? Once I get this working, I will be complete. provided I can replicate the settings in the regular paypal site

Comment: I think that might just be a sandbox thing. I'll test the last one I did in sandbox and confirm as soon as I can. But as long as it's turned on with a URL set and saved it will auto-return.

Comment: Thanks for that tidbit. Did you manage to test your sandbox? I thought it was a setting in my account. The question then becomes, "If sandbox does not honor the auto return, how do I know that buyers will be automatically returned when not using sandbox?"  I can't possibly run a live payment to test or can I if the amount charged is zero?

Comment: I just checked and don't see the auto return setting in sandbox under profile settings. Maybe it only works in the live site? If that is the case, I am all set... I think... I've not been able to test and be 100% certain. Maybe I should sell one copy of the book to myself for $0 to test functionality.

Comment: I just tested and Sandbox did not auto-redirect. My production redirects just fine. So you are probably good to go. But that $0 test would do the trick

Comment: PayPal won't let me make a purchase of $0. I sacrificed a penny to verify that auto return works. I now get to go to my merchant account and send the penny back to my other account. Now I need the office I'm building the form for to get me a PayPal account they intend to use.

Answer (score 0):

The idea was not to use an IPN listener (way more than I need), but rather to ask the customer how many books they wanted and add a single item to the PayPal cart: "# - 2015 Catholic Directory" where # is the quantity. The price for the book then becomes Quantity * $15. This way I can sell any quantity I want.

My database gets filled with customer information including quantity as a separate field when they fill out the order form and then that info gets sent on to PayPal to complete payment. Also I setup PayPal to auto return back to my site when the payment is complete and then mark the order as paid. This way I can develop reports for the office selling the books indicating who ordered how many books and if payment has been received.

Problem solved.  The only thing I found difficult with the process was the fact that the sandbox environment does not have auto return like the live payment system does. I had to run a dummy sale for a penny and then refund the penny to verify the auto return was working.